# Is lexical stress mostly consistent across accents of Standard English?

Tags: accent, stress

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_and_vowel_reduction_in_English#Lexical_and_prosodic_stress), lexical stress in Standard English* is "phonemic" (whatever they think they mean by that), using the minimal pair *insight/incite* as an example. My hypothesis is that, across Standard English, lexical stress is mostly consistent. I am however not very familiar with the many different English accents, so I wonder whether this is true.

Note that I'm specifically *not* considering prosodic stress, or how stress is realised (inflection, vowel length, etc.) in different accents. I'm only asking about one part of the puzzle: if Standard English speakers are asked to mark the stress of words, would they mostly agree**, regardless of their accent?

---

* I know, this is a vague term. I'm mostly concerned about what's called "native English" in North America, the British Isles, Australia, and New Zealand. If you believe that's too narrow of a definition, please don't hesitate to comment on that.

** If you need a metric for agreement: the correlation of the placement of primary lexical stress for each word (only distinguished by exact spelling and part of speech, to account for details like heteronyms and unexpected spellings), weighed according to that word's frequency (in a corpus of your choice, which usually also comes with a preferred PoS inventory).

Comment: "Pecan" is the first counter example that springs to mind.  There are many others. I suppose it depends on what "mostly consistent" means.

Comment: Now *this* is the kind of question I would love to see more of on ELU.

Comment: You say poh-TAY-to, I say pah-tah-TO.  You say CER-a-bral, I say ce-REE-bral.  I refute it thus.

Comment: @jejorda2 That is an interesting example. I updated the question to clarify what I mean by consistency, but I unfortunately can't qualify what I mean by "mostly".

Comment: @cobaltduck I can't find an audio example of "tomato", but "cerebral" is a good counterexample.

Comment: So "consistency" measures the differences in stresses reported in various dictionaries?  I don't understand what you think that has to do with dialect variation in stress, or whether stress is phonemic, or anything of interest.

Comment: @GregLee Not exactly. That question is more to emphasise the aspect I'm interested in, rather than who to ask. I'll edit the question.

Comment: You say a-DULT, I say AH-dult. You say ga-RAJH, I say GA-rij. You say FER-tl, I say fer-TILE.

Comment: Closed by {moderators}: let's call the whole thing off.

Comment: @DanBron Not me.  I'm looking forward to the next request for proofreading a resume.  But that's only because I enjoy watching Ranthony get medieval on posters.

Comment: As you note yourself, this question is unclear. What is the set that you are asking whether it is consistent? One could define a variety by it being consistent (to a certain degree) within a set of people. Are you asking if individuals are consistent (eg does an individual consistently put stress in one spot for 'insurance'? Yes, I think so. With all people of given geographical variety (yes, but in free variation near the border). For all of English? No, different varieties have different stress for some words.

Comment: Suggestion: I personally find certain aspects of the question too broad to even get a foothold. But this could easily be resolved by a sampling of words, particularly examples you feel relevant AND examples to exclude. For instance IN-sight vs in-CITE represents a very specific category, where the phonemic stress occurs entirely on a syllable level without changing any vowel pronunciation.  But poe-TAY-toh vs pah-tah-TOH & CER-a-bral vs ce-REE-bral (as mentioned by @cobaltduck ) both have vowel differences and syllabic stress differences. In that category it's hard to tell cause vs effect.

Comment: @H.R.Rambler I understand what you mean with the interplay between vowel type and stress, but I was only looking for stress, and my question was not at all at a point where I was considering any causal relation. This general question arose from reading about spelling reforms, and my observation that syllabication and lexical stress rules are rarely part of proposals. I know that phoneme choice/realisation and prosodic stress may differ greatly between SE accents, but I was wondering if the same was true for just lexical stress.

Comment: That's pretty much what I expected your intention to be. I think that if you add this bit of clarification to the question it may help. Maybe even something simple like "There are going to be some words where pronunciation norms change the vowels or even syllable breaks. This may cloud the lexical stress question. Please feel free to treat those as outliers exempted from the 'Standard'."

Comment: The word "concrete" is usually "CON crete" as a noun but "con CRETE" as an adjective. In the southern US both uses are "CON crete." We see something similar with the word "cement." Although in southern US the noun and verb have both been pronounced "CE ment" lately the verb form has been transitioning to the more widely used "ce MENT."

Comment: Regarding spelling reform, there would be no need to denote differing stress in situations where the part of speech determines stress. Example, "Who rejected this reject?"    "re JECT" is a verb and "RE ject" is a noun.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will defer to someone who can provide more explicit references, but I'm going to say "yes, it is mostly consistent", for two reasons:

- ["J. C. Wells: Accents of English"](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/accentsanddialects/) (by John C. Wells, the famous British phonetician), in summarizing the phonetic features of the various major accents of English, mentions word stress only twice:

  - In the West Indies, "Words such as real**ize** are stressed on the last syllable."
  - In India, "word stress sometimes deviates from that of other accents (*acquire* [ˈɛkʋaɪɹ])."

  Additionally, it mentions that RP has a "[w]eak suffix in *-ary*: *moment**ary*** /ˈməʊməntrɪ/; but not in *-ile*: *host**ile*** /ˈhɒstaɪl/". Under some analyses, these would be differences in secondary stress between different accents; under other analyses, unreduced vowels are not inherently considered stressed, so these would just be differences in vowel reduction, not in stress. (Wells apparently subscribes to the latter camp, else he would presumably have written /ˈhɒsˌtaɪl/.)
- Anecdotally: when I've listened to non-American accents, I've frequently noticed differences in stress placement in various words, such as *protester* and [*elsewhere*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/308901/14775), but my experience is that these are by far the exception rather than the rule.

Of course, even within an accent, there is often variation between different speakers, especially in less-common words.

Comment: In Southern US English and African American English, there is a tendency to pronounce words like *po**lice***, *T**V*** (*tee**vee***), and *De**troit*** as ***po**lice*, ***T**V* (***tee**vee*), and ***De**troit*.

Comment: @Matt: I'm not very familiar with Southern US English, but as far as AAVE goes, I don't think ***De**troit* is very common (at least among people who actually live in the general area of Detroit). I'm also not sure about ***po**lice*; I've definitely heard it with a full vowel in the first syllable, but I *think* the stress is usually on the second syllable (so, rhythmically analogous to the last two syllables of "Little Bo Peep").

Comment: @Matt: (To your general point, though: yes, if we broaden scope beyond Standard English, we'll find more words where stress placement varies between dialects. In fact, even within Standard English, there are a lot of words where stress placement varies; it's just that these are vastly, vastly outnumbered by words where it doesn't. And I think that probably remains true even when we consider dialects that aren't considered "Standard English".)